# Add the "Days Visited" metric to SEDE

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, visited-days

I was writing a query on SEDE, when I noticed there was no "Days Visited" value.

[image]

<sup>I have circled the available user metrics, alas there is no Days Visited</sup>

While there is a *CreationDate*, this can't be used as accuretly in queries as me (and other people) create accounts on sites but then rarely visit the site.

I'd use this to weight user "scores" but they are probably a lot more uses for this.

Comment: To be clear, do you mean the number of unique days they have visited the site? I'm pretty sure that's not public information, and that SEDE does not publish any information that is not already made available to the general public outside of iteself.